# Topological isomorphism Pontryagin Dual

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups

Let $T=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ denote the unit circle. For each $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, define $\chi_y:\mathbb{R}^n\to T$ by $\chi_y(x) =xy+\mathbb{Z}$,  where $xy$ denotes the scalar product of $x$ and $y$. Then $y\to \chi_y$ is a group isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n\to \hat{\mathbb{R}^n}$, where $\hat{\mathbb{R}^n}$ denotes Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is that is this isomorphism also an isomorphism of topological groups, where Pontryagin dual has topology of compact convergence.

Comment: Compose with $\exp(2i\pi z)$ (continuous bounded homomorphisms to $\Bbb{C}^\times$ is what we need for the Fourier transform). Given $y_0\in \Bbb{R}^n$ and $r >0$ can you find $K\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ compact and $s>0$ such that $\{ y, \forall x\in K, |\exp(2i\pi x^\top y)-\exp(2i\pi x^\top y_0)|<s\}\subset \{ y,\|y-y_0\|< r\}$ ?

Comment: I had reduced the problem to precisely your comment. It would be great if you could just provide one such compact set $K$ and $s>0$.

Comment: Take $K$ the ball of radius $1/(2r)$, if $\|y-y_0\|\ge r>0$ then $x=\frac{y-y_0}{2\|y-y_0\|^2}\in K$ gives $\exp(2i\pi x^\top (y-y_0)) = -1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like  a charm.